# Print Dynamic Table Area

Tags: excel, vba, printing, range

All,

I have the following code:

```
Sub PrintFinalMTO()

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("J" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = Range("$B$5:$M" & lastrow)
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
End With

End Sub
```

When the macro is run, the print preview contains range (A1:M) instead of starting at B5.  The table extends to column M but the last row will have a value in column J. The print range is correct aside from the rows above B5.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `.PrintArea` is expecting a range address. I have just checked [PageSetup.PrintArea Property (Excel):](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.PageSetup.PrintArea) which appears to confirm my belief.

Can you put:

```
.PrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range("$B$5:$M" & lastrow).Address
```

From the link I gave:

> This example sets the print area to the current region on Sheet1. Note
> that you use the Address property to return an A1-style address.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate  
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address
```

Comment: It still gives me rows 1 through 4, but it works. It's odd.  Even when I go to "page break preview" the blue line only encloses b5 :m but it still prints rows 1 through 4.

Comment: It doesn't for me. Do you have anything like a filter on the sheet?

Comment: As an aside, explicitly reference the worksheet you are dealing with. Something like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") . It's safer and easier to debug. And is your table an actual excel table? i.e. [ListObject](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

Comment: Still doesn't work.  This even pulls up an error, so it is worse than before.

Comment: Define pulls up an error? Is there a specific error message? What is it? Has this error occured because of fully qualifying? There must be something else going on in your sheet. If i run the code as I have posted I get only the range of interest in the print review irrespective of if I have data in rows 1:4. Can you post a screenshot of your table?

Comment: Qharr, I figured it out.  It should be:
       .PrintArea = "$B5:$M" & lastrow
Thanks for you help.

Comment: that is the same as putting ActiveSheet.Range("$B$5:$M" & lastrow).Address It yields a string.

Comment: Okay, it has to be something with this computer because I got it to work another computer but not this one.  If i change to 5 to 20, it will show rows 20 and below but it still includes rows 1 through 4.  If no one responds, I'll understand this is probably something too simple for anyone to waster their time with.  Thanks for everyone's patience.

Comment: At present, without seeing your data layout, which may help pinpoint the real source of the problem, I cannot duplicate the issue. The code I wrote works. I’m sorry.

Comment: I don’t know if there are any application level settings at play. Wouldn’t have thought so.

Comment: Fixed.  Under the page setup tab, under print titles there is a section that says "rows to repeat at top" for some reason 1-4 was chosen. I don't know how.  Thanks for your time, QHarr.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you got there :-)